# Angularjs filter overriding and module dependency injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My application depends on two filter applications like

```
 var app = angular.module('MyApp',['Filter1','Filter2']);
```

where both the applications have **filters with same name** like

```
 var filterapp1 = angular.module('Filter1',[]);
 filterapp1.filter('replace',function(){return function(input){ 
             return input + " from Filter1 app";
 }});

 var filterapp2 = angular.module('Filter2',[]);
 filterapp2.filter('replace',function(){return function(input){ 
             return input + " from Filter2 app";
 }});
```

Now in my application if i want to refer the filter from the filterapplication1, How can i can i do?

In my HTML i have something like

```
 {{'Hello World' | replace }}
```

where the output should be "Hello World from Filter1 app" but i am getting "Hello World from Filter2 app". How to override the filters? Or **do filters override by order they are injected?** How to overcome this?

Comment: JsFiddle Added. http://jsfiddle.net/yesoreyeram/qDFsB/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Angular "last one wins". So if you want to use both filters, you should name them differently. For example, filter('module1.replace',....)

Comment: Thank valentyn. But how it is possible with big application with multiple modules.

Comment: In my practice we started naming keeping in mind that AngularJS has 'last wins' principle, so we just named everything inside module prefixing module name.